# single post request from multiple partial view from single form in MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

In MVC form three tabs  Personal, Address, Contact and each form has its own partial view which render on tab click.
Below is the HTML of my form

```
<ul id="divTabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
<li role="presentation" class="active">
@Ajax.ActionLink("Personal", "Personal", "ProfileManage", new AjaxOptions()
{
       HttpMethod = "Post",
       UpdateTargetId = "divTabsContent",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})
</li>
<li role="presentation">
@Ajax.ActionLink("Address", "Address", "ProfileManage", new AjaxOptions()
{
       HttpMethod = "Post",
       UpdateTargetId = "divTabsContent",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})
</li>
<li role="presentation">
@Ajax.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "ProfileManage", new AjaxOptions()
{
       HttpMethod = "POST",
       UpdateTargetId = "divTabsContent",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})
</li>
</ul>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxPost", "ProfileManage", new AjaxOptions()
{

    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "divTabsContent",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}))
{   
 <div id="divTabsContent" class="tab-content tab-pane bordered">
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/ProfileManage/_DetailPersonal.cshtml", Model);
 </div>
}
```

Inside each partial view(Personal,Address,Contact) there is submit button
So how can i differentiate post request is from which partial view in controller post request.

Comment: simple approach will be to have seperate forms for each tab

Comment: i'd used pure html+jquery without mvc wrappers, to be more fluent

Comment: yes to create new form for each tab is simplest approach but it is not feasible to me because if i have to add new tab then i have to go for each page and add new tab link or same for removing the tab this is an error process